# RavenDb objects instantiation

Tags: .net, nosql, ravendb

I have noticed RavenDb doesn't require entities to have default constructor. How does it create objects during queries then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idsa,
The way it works, when you have a ctor and a json, we try to match the ctor parameters to the json properties and see if we can make it work.

This behavior is built into Json.NET

Answer (score 0):

I believe RavenDB can't handle this automatically. RavenDB serializes to JSON using the Newtonsoft JSON library, if I'm not mistaken. Thus, you have to provide it a custom resolver.

See ['Immutable entities'](http://ravendb.net/faq/immutable-entities) on the RavenDB FAQ, and [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/7477876025e81188) on the Raven DB Google Group for some more info.

Comment: Quote from discussion you mentioned: "The JsonSerializer 
seems to just work as-is without any customization". So it really works (and I see it in my application). I am just curious how it is implemented

Answer (score -1):

When you dont specify one Visual Studio automatically generates one in the IL.

If you specified a private no arguments constructor the default public no arguments constructor would not be generated.

As an experiment try adding a default no arguments private constructor to test this theory. I would assume RavenDb might have an issue with this.

Comment: I have an entity with one non-default public consructor and I don't see RavenDb has any issues with it. I am just curious why it is so